# Android ProgressDialog context problems

Tags: android, progressdialog, android-context

Quick summary: I'm making an application that parses a binary file, stores vertices and their properties, and displays them in openGL. I'm trying to implement a **ProgressDialog** while it parses, but I'm having considerable trouble. I've tried implementing this in many places, but this is my current setup:

```
    public class PointViewer extends Activity{
     ...
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
            filePath = extras.getString("file_path");

            mGLView = new GLSurfaceView(this);
            theRenderer = new OpenGLRenderer();
            mGLView.setRenderer(theRenderer);
            //Parse the file and set the arrays
            theRenderer.setLAS(filePath);
            setContentView(mGLView);

        }
     ...
    }
```

The Rendering class...

```
public class OpenGLRenderer extends Activity implements GLSurfaceView.Renderer {
         ...
            public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            }

            public void setLAS (String fileName){

                new ProgressTask(this).execute();


            }
        ...
        /*
         * The class for the progress dialog 
        */
        private class ProgressTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {
           private ProgressDialog dialog;
           private Context context;

           //private List<Message> messages;
           public ProgressTask(Context ctx) {

               context = ctx;
               dialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
           }



           /** progress dialog to show user that the backup is processing. */

           protected void onPreExecute() {
               this.dialog.setMessage("Progress start");
               this.dialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
               this.dialog.show();
           }

            @Override
           protected void onPostExecute(final Boolean success) {


               if (dialog.isShowing()) {
                   dialog.dismiss();
               }

               if (success) {
                   Toast.makeText(context, "OK", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
               } else {
                   Toast.makeText(context, "Error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
               }
           }

           protected Boolean doInBackground(final String... args) {
               try{    
                ptCloud = new PointCloud(args[0]);

                    ...

                   dialog.setProgress(percentParsed);
                   return true;
                } catch (Exception e){
                   Log.e("tag", "error", e);
                   return false;
                }
             }


}
```

When I call **dialog = new ProgressDialog(context);** It errors on a null pointer exception, I'm assuming because there is a context issue... Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Unable to start activity.... ERROR/AndroidRuntime(25782):     at ...OpenGLRenderer$ProgressTask.<init>(OpenGLRenderer.java:303), the one I marked in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

maybe try replaceing "this" with "OpenGLRenderer.this" inside your setLAS() method. It doesn't seem like it from the code you've posted but sometimes if you are making that call from a different object type it will try to pass in an OnClickListener (or whatever object your calling from) instead of an activity, thus the object has no context. Like I said doesn't seem like that is the case, but worth a shot.

Also where are you calling setLAS() from? perhaps post that section of your code too.

Edit:

Try modifying your setLAS() method to have a Context parameter and pass it in from your first activity, and just pass it along from the second activity to the async task instead of using the context from the second activity.

Comment: Yeah I thought of that too, I just tried it and the error is exactly the same. setLAS() is called in the first block of code I posted, before I setContentView(). -thanks!

Comment: This made everything functional except that the ProgressDialog doesn't update over time, I would suspect inazaruk knows why this is. - Awesome help thank you!

Answer (score 3):

First, you shouldn't create `OpenGLRenderer` yourself, because its an `Activity` and is supposed to be managed by system. When you create `OpenGLRenderer` yourself, then this activity has its context incorrectly initialized. And when your create ProgressDialog with invalid context, you receive `NullPointerException`.

---

But even if you start `OpenGlRenderer` correctly, your app will still crash at line:

```
dialog.setProgress(percentParsed);
```

You should use [`publishProgress`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#publishProgress%28Progress...%29) instead and update ProgressDialog in AsyncTask's [`onProgressUpdate`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#onProgressUpdate%28Progress...%29) function. That's because you can't update UI from non-ui thread.

Comment: I looked at the onProgressUpdate function online when I was writing this, but does that have to be manually called somewhere? When does it get handled. Also, at this point does that even matter, since I can't create the dialog? How else would I setup my renderer?

Comment: I should also say that before I through in the dialog idea and the AsyncTask functionality, everything worked great.

Comment: I've updated the answer about why you receive exception when creating dialog. Also, about `onProgressUpdate`, this function is called on UI thread after you call `publishProgress` from your `doInBackground()` function.

Comment: I'm confused about what you mean by "create OpenGLRenderer yourself". When I was reviewing OpenGL a few weeks back everyone seemed to do it exactly like I had here (minus the activity extension, which I wanted to get context passed through). I guess I'm just confused on how to get the correct context, since it was working find until the dialog implementation. -Thank you for your help, too

Comment: Then do not extend `Activity`  and path `Context` value as parameter as to constructor of `OpenGLRenderer`. For example save context to `mContext` field, and when you are going to create `ProgressDialog` you'll use `new ProgressDialog(mContext)`.

Comment: Okay that makes sense. I have one more question though. In the end of my code in the doInBackground method  I have "ptCloud = new PointCloud(args[0]);" which actually does the parsing, I tried putting publishProgress(ptCloud.getPercent); but it isn't responding...